# Paste columns side by side on many files using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, paste

I've been struggling for quite a while on this problem (please note I'm not a really good bash coder, let alone awk). 
I have about 10000 files, each formated the same way (quite heavy as well, about 3Mb). I would like to get the 3rd row of each file and paste them side by side on a new file.

I found many solutions using paste, awk, or cut, but none of them worked when working with wildcards. For instance,

```
paste <(awk '{print $3}' file1 ) <(awk '{print $3}' file2 ) <(awk '{print $3}' file3) > output
```

would work great if I only had 3 files, but I won't type that for 10000 of them. So I gave it a try with wildcards:

```
paste <(awk '{print $3}' file* ) > output
```

And it does paste the 3rd rows, but in a single line. I tried some other codes, but eventually always end up with the same result. Is there a way to paste them side by side using wildcards?

Thank you very much for your help!

Baptiste G.

> EDIT 1: With the help of schorsch312, I found a solution that works
>   for me. Instead of getting the columns and pasting them side by side,
>   I print each columns as a line and add them one after the other:
>
> for i in `ls files*`; do
>          awk '{printf $3i" "}END{print}' $i >> output done
>
> It works but 1/ it's quite slow, and 2/ it's not exactly what I asked
>   in the title, as my output files is the "transpose". It doesn't really
>   matter to me because it's only floats and I can transpose it later
>   with python if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you said awk alone, but I don't know how to do it. Here is a simple bash script which does what you like to do.

```
# do a loop over all your files 
for i in `ls file*`; do 
    # use awk to get the 3rd row for all files and save output
    awk '{print $3}' $i > row_$i  
done

# now paste your rows together.
paste row_* > output

# cleanup
rm row_*
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't really care if it's not a one-liner solution, just whatever works. However, this solution doesn't work as paste doesn't allow me to manipulate so many files:

>  paste: row_fault_01021.xyz: Too many open files

Comment: :-) You can use paste in the for loop ( paste output row_$i >> output). You need to use >> in order to override output.

Comment: I though about it, but for some reasons the loop get stuck after 1 iteration (and nothing computes anymore). However with your loop idea, I found a solution that somewhat works (I edited my post). Thanks!